# Twig: How to get the first character in a string

Tags: symfony, twig

I am implementing an alphabetical search.
We display a table of Names. I want to highlight only those alphabets, which have names that begin with the corresponding alphabet.

I am stumped with a simple problem.

How to read the first character in the string user.name within twig. 
I have tried several strategies, including the [0] operation but it throws an exception.
Here is the code

```
{% for i in ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0-9'] %}
       {% set has_user_starting_with_alphabet = false %}
       {% for user in pagination %}
              {% if user.name[0]|lower == i %}
                      {% set has_user_starting_with_alphabet = true %}
              {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
       {% if has_user_starting_with_alphabet %}
              <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), { 'search_key' : i}) }}"><span>{{ i }}</span></a></li>
       {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there some function like "starts_with" in twig?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Since twig 1.12.2 you can use [`first`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/first.html):

```
{% if user.name|first|lower == i %}
```

For older version you can use [`slice`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html):

```
{% if user.name|slice(0, 1)|lower == i %}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** You may also use this notation:

`{% if user.name[:1]|lower == i %}`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: He asks how to get the first letter of a string. `user.name[:1]` does exacly that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make the code a lot simpler, probably:

```
{% set character = user.name|first|lower %}

{% if character in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789' %}
   <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), { 'search_key' : character}) }}"><span>{{ character }}</span></a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Or depending on the use case:

```
<li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), { 'search_key' : user.name|first|lower}) }}"><span>{{ user.name|first|lower }}</span></a></li>
```