# How to extract the first letter of a word with TWIG?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8, drupal-views

In a Drupal 8 views, I have a field with a token.

How to extract the first letter of a word with TWIG ?

I just want to display the first letter of the token in this field.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSoJl.png)

I tested the following code, but it doesn't work :

```
{{ '{{ name }}'|first }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out :

```
{{ name|first }}
```

or

```
{{ name|slice(0, 1) }}
```

[Twig: How to get the first character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998914/twig-how-to-get-the-first-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

for a text field you can use :

```
content.field_lastname.0['#context'].value[0:1]
```